# Load time with AngularJS, Cloudant and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, curl, cloudant

I'm building a SPA that has the following process:

1. Load index.html
2. Load main app .js file
3. The JS file makes a http get
   to a PHP file
4. The PHP file makes a CURL request to Cloudant for all
   docs
5. The callback in the JS file takes the data, makes some
   operation and displays it in the frontent.

As of now, grabbing all dependencies from a CDN, the total load time of the site is 1.2s. The problem comes with the PHP/CURL, which streches the load until 4s (**TTFB is 2.59s**).

Is there something in the successions of events that could be improved or done more efficiently?

I'm finding 4 seconds to be a bit too much, and I'm pretty certain I might have missed something, considering that is my first SPA with backend.

Here's my JS:

```
var $promisedb=$http.get('test2/getall.php'); 

$promisedb.then(function (data) {
    console.log(data)
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.data = data.data.rows;
    ... do stuff
};
```

And my PHP:

```
<?php
    $url = "https://user:pass@user.cloudant.com/db/_all_docs?include_docs=true";
    $ch = curl_init();   // initialize curl handle
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: If the 'curl' part is your issue and data doesn't change very often why not considering to cache this response to avoid the call? This could be even done on JS level before starting the PHP call

Comment: The thing is that because of the use of the application, the site will be always open, then I'll create a refresh function to see if there's new data. Even so, almost 3 seconds to get the data response seems a bit on the upper side...

Comment: sorry i don't get your comment

Comment: I mean that even if I cache the data, refreshes on the data will need to be done often (x2-4 a day), so it doesn't help much..

Comment: given your spare information getting down each request(!) down by seconds  compared to a cache refresh 2-4 times a day(!) doesn't help much? then I can't help you, sorry.

Comment: @LBA maybe I'm misunderstanding something.. When I call the data, I call all docs. Even if I cache the existing data with JS, I still need to make the calls to refresh it, don't I? And if I need to make the call, it will still take 2-3 seconds to refresh the cache? I'd be grateful if you'd expand on how to approach this.